How do I create a type that matches a Map's value?
A JavaScript Map object has the type Map<K, V>. I would like to create a type that matches V.
For example:
function addItemToMap(map: Map) {
    return function addItem(id: string, item: V) {
       return map.set(id, item)
    }
}

When I call this function, I'd like to be sure that the item I'm passing is able to be added to the map:
// This should ensure that `bar` is a value that can go into the map `foo`
addItemToMap(foo)('x', bar)

TypeScript playground with a slightly more through example

type ItemType = ValueOf<State>; seems close to what you need which is used in combination with: type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T] extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;. Although TypeScript makes you narrow the types in the add basket function as opposed to statically when it's called.

Given the code that's actually in the question as plain text, this approach is how you should do it. But your "slightly more th[o]rough example" is a different issue, which is ms/TS#30581 and needs quite a different set of machinery to make it be seen as type safe by the compiler. So, what is the actual question here? Please [edit] to clarify which thing you're trying to do.

(see prev comment) This approach is how you'd deal with the code in your playground link. If that's the actual use case then please do [edit] to put that in the question directly, and I'll be happy to write up an answer explaining. If it isn't, or if I'm missing something, let me know.
